# String manipulations in C++ using strtok

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do some string manipulations from a .gz file.
and I've written the following code.

```
char buffer[1001];
for(;gzeof(f_Handle);){
    gzread(f_Handle, buffer, 1000);
    buffer[1000] = 0;
    char* chars_array = strtok(buffer, " ");

    while(chars_array){
        cout<<chars_array << '\n';
        chars_array = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

However the file format (.gz) is in

```
A 1 2 3
B 2 3 5
A 4 5 6
B 34 64 123
```

and I want to know when it is an A or B and the contents in A or B separately .

currently, it prints it out in the followng manner

```
A
1
2
3
...
```

Idea a) is to use a if loop thru the chars_array to find out A or B or

b) string array instead of char pointer

Comment: Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: Can you give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example using `std::string` and the function `substr(...)` It won't do the entire string, but you can put it in a loop to do that.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string original = "01234567 89abc defghi j";
    std::vector< std::string > strings;

    // Find space from last index
    int lastSpaceIndex = 0;
    int spaceIndex = original.find( ' ', lastSpaceIndex );

    // Find the number of characters to split
    int numCharacters = spaceIndex - lastSpaceIndex;

    // Split string ( the second argument is the number of characters to splut out)
    std::string tokenizedString = original.substr( lastSpaceIndex, numCharacters );

    // Add to vector of strings
    strings.push_back( tokenizedString);

    // Print result
    std::cout << "Space at : " << spaceIndex << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Tokenized string : " << tokenizedString << std::endl;

    // Find the nextsubstring
    // =========================================================================
    // Need to increase by 1 since we don't want the space 
    lastSpaceIndex = spaceIndex + 1;
    spaceIndex = original.find( ' ', lastSpaceIndex );

    numCharacters = spaceIndex - lastSpaceIndex;
    tokenizedString = original.substr( lastSpaceIndex, numCharacters );

     strings.push_back( tokenizedString);

    std::cout << "Space at : " << spaceIndex << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Tokenized string : " << tokenizedString << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=====================================\n";

    for ( const auto &str : strings )
    {
        std::cout << "String : " << str << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Output :

```
Space at : 8
Tokenized string : 01234567
Space at : 14
Tokenized string : 89abc
=====================================
String : 01234567
String : 89abc
```

---

When there are no more spaces, the `original.find( ' ', lastSpaceIndex )` will return `std::npos`